# ionic platform add android - are these necessary directories?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

When I run either of the following commands:

```
$ ionic platform add android
```

or

```
$ ionic run android -l
```

the plugins on the directory:

```
<root>/plugins
```

are copied to the directory:

```
<root>/platforms/android/assets/www/plugins
```

[image]

Inside each plugin directory there is one `JavaScript` file.

In the other hand, inside the directory:

```
<root>/platforms/android/assets/www/build
```

there is one compiled javascript file: `main.js`

[image]

So, my question is if I need the following directory?

```
<root>/platforms/android/assets/www/plugins
```

In case the application doesn't need it, how can I remove it during the execution of the two first commands above?

Comment: How do you mean though? When you build for android you should just have a `.apk` file for the final application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `<root>/platforms/android/assets/www/build` you find the .js files of your application (the code you create for your application). In `<root>/platforms/android/assets/www/plugins` you find a single folder and one or more .js files for every plugin you add to your project, these .js files are part of the bridge between the javascript part in the webview and the native (Java or ObjC) code of the plugins. So deleting them would break cordovas plugin system.